# rmagick auto pointsize and wrap text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, text, annotations, carrierwave, rmagick

how can I make rmagick wrap the annotation text on the picture and then auto scale the font size and add line breaks? It's for something like a meme generator.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
phrase = 'Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.'
BACKGROUND_PATH = Rails.root.join('image_dir', 'background.jpg')    
background = Magick::Image.read(BACKGROUND_PATH).first
img = Magick::Image.read("caption:#{phrase}") do
  # puts self.methods
  self.size = '500x'
  self.background_color = 'none'
  self.pointsize = 30
  self.font = 'Tahoma'
  self.fill = 'gray'
  self.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity #Text orientation
end.first
#                          Text box orientation    #left(20), #right(40)
background.composite!(img, Magick::NorthEastGravity, 20, 40, Magick::OverCompositeOp)
background.write(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'my_image.jpg'))
```